# Find the limit of the series $6^n/n!$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to find the limit of the following serie:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}$$\frac{6^n}{n!}$

I was thinking of the following solution, but i'm not sure it's correct, please let me know your thoughts :)

$0$ $<$ $\frac{6^n}{n!}$ $<$ $\frac{6}{1}\cdot$$\frac{6}{2}\cdot$ $\frac{6}{3}\cdot$$\frac{6}{4}\cdot$$\frac{6}{5}\cdot$$\frac{6}{6}\cdot$ $1\cdot$ $1\cdot$ $1\cdot$ .... $\cdot1\cdot$ $\frac{6}{n}$ $=$ $\frac{1944}{5n}$

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}$$0$ $= 0$

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}$$\frac{1944}{5n}$ $= 0$

Hence, by using the sandwich theorem, $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}$$\frac{6^n}{n!}$ $= 0$.

Comment: Compare $6^n$ with $n!$. As $n$ grows, which number gets bigger more quickly, comparatively speaking?

Comment: What doubts do you have about your solution?

Comment: thought maybe the last limit of 1944/5n should be also proven for being 0..

Comment: For that you can use the definition of the limit. For any $\epsilon > 0$, you can find some $N$ such that $1944/5N < \epsilon$, and for all $n>N$ this would be true as well. Hence, zero is the limit of this sequence.

Comment: Use [ratio test for sequences](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid solution. The upper bound you provide works for $n > 6$, but this is okay for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about the exponential function, you can argue as follows:

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{6^n}{n!}$ converges to $e^6$ and so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6^n}{n!}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps overkill, but it works:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6^n}{n}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{6^{x-1}}{\Gamma(x)}=L$$
$$\log(L)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\log(6^{x-1})-\log\Gamma(x)\right)$$
[Series expansion of log Gamma](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html):
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[(x-1)\log6-(-\gamma x-\ln x+...)\right]=-\infty$$
$$\log(L)=-\infty\implies L=0.$$